# How to dynamically implement ellipsis in angular 7

Tags: css, angular7, ellipsis

I have dynamic content with Image, description [MultipLine] and it is responsive.
I want to display [ellipsis]... in description based on the space of the div. I tried many css but seems it's not working with multiple lines.
Can anyone please help with this in angular 7?

```
  <a [ngStyle]="{background: 'url(' + Image + ') right bottom no-repeat'}">
        
            <span>{{name}}</span> // Here I want to add ellipsis dynamically and it should work in responsive way
    </a>
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to achieve and maybe add a code exmaple?

Comment: @QuentinAlbert I am trying to add my case with code, Thanks